# How do I redirect to 404 page when any records do not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

eg. I have student and teacher model. if i visited the student or teacher profile that not exists in db it will raise as ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

I have tried this in the application controller but still got an error message **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound** instead of **404 page**.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
end
```

So, is there a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :)

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

      private

      def record_not_found
        render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: true, status: :not_found
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^apt_adm - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error.php [L]
```